# Simplifying Long Javascript IFs

Tags: javascript, variables

I found this on the internet on how to make an if stament smaller:

```
if([1,5,7,22].indexOf(myvar)!=-1) alert('yeah')
```

From this:

```
if( myvar==1 || myvar==5 || myvar==7 || myvar==22 ) alert('yeah')
```

Is there a way to do this where instead of having 4 myvar, there are 3 different values? What I want is for the original statement to be:

```
if(i('b').style.display == a[1] & i('c').style.display == a[1] & i('d').style.display == a[1])
```

I want to try shorten this as much as possible... any points? I have searched the internet a lot about this and found nothing...

Comment: Not much shorter, but less repetition: `['b','c','d'].map(x => i(x).style.display).every(x => x == a[1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler (but arguably less readable) form of your if expression would be

```
if(['b','c','d'].filter(letter => i(letter).style.display === a[1]).length === 3)
```

The [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) executes the filter test function for each element in the array and creates a new array of letters that match the `i(letter).style.display == a[1]` condition. Since you'd like to do something only when all three letters pass the test, the if-expression checks if the length of the new array is 3.

**Edit**: Shorter version (based on Felix Kling's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656665/simplifying-long-javascript-ifs/41656812#comment70512266_41656665))

```
if(['b','c','d'].every(letter => i(letter).style.display === a[1]))
```